# Error in approx(nintv, cvals[nintl:ninth, tintl, i], n = max(nintv) - : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to apply the second generation panel unit root tests (CIPS test) using function `cipstest()` of package `plm` in R.

I am getting this error:

> Error in approx(nintv, cvals[nintl:ninth, tintl, i], n = max(nintv) -
> : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate.

There are no missing values in my data.
Could you help me with this subject?

```
library("plm")
df1 <- pdata.frame(df, index = c("country", "year"), drop.index = TRUE)
cipstest(df1$AVA, lags = 2, type = "trend")
```

Comment: Hi, you might want to add some [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier to understand the problem and give you an answer.

Comment: I suspect you do not have enough data points in the time dimension of your panel for the test to be executable.